# Open pop-up window inside Model window no errors сrash after compiling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

The home page allows you to open a model window in which there are fields for data, at the same time I try to make a button in the same model window that opens a pop-up window with which you can select several photos, after confirming the pop-up window closes and the selected photos appear in the mode slide under fields, like I said no errors in code, after compiling I can see Home page, but when I try to open this model window (where all fields and popup) it's crashes with error:

**Attempted to scroll the collection view to an out-of-bounds item (0) when there are only 0 items in section 0. Collection view: *and many different words and meanings that are unlikely to help because there is no end to them and of course there is nothing on Google about this either***

*I tried as much as possible to remove the extra code, which is in no way related to the problem for readability.*

[This is how my model window looks like (there are no cancel and save buttons on the toolBar, but in the code they already exist and work) -the screenshot was taken when this model window was still open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3zOq.png)

**AddItemsView** - // Problem in this part of code

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("New Item")) {
                TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.singleitem.title)
                TextField("Description", text: $viewModel.singleitem.description)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Author")) {
                TextField("Author", text: $viewModel.singleitem.author)
            }
            
            if mode == .edit {
                Section {
                    Button("Delete item") { self.presentActionSheet.toggle() }
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            } 
            Section(footer: // TABVIEW WITH POPUP WINDOW STARTS HERE

                
                TabView {
                    
                    ForEach(pickedImages, id: \.self) { image in
                        
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            
                            let size = proxy.size
                            Image(uiImage: image)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(height: 450)
                // MARK: Swift UI Bug
                
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: pickedImages.isEmpty ? .never :  .always))
                .toolbar {
                    Button {
                        
                        showPicker.toggle()
                        
                    } label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        
                    }
                }
            
            .popupImagePicker(show: $showPicker) { asset in
                
                // MARK: Example of Kavsoft
                let manager = PHCachingImageManager.default()
                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.isSynchronous = true
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    asset.forEach { asset in
                        
                        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: .init(), contentMode: .default, options: options) { image, _ in
                            
                            guard let image = image else { return }
                         
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                self.pickedImages.append(image)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }

            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
         }
 //       .navigationBarItems(leading: cancelButton, trailing: saveButton)
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. There is so much un related code it makes it difficult to troubleshoot, try making a minimal example.

Comment: @loremipsum I only figured out where the problem is, the problem is that the tabview somehow conflicts inside the `NavigationView`, 
I minimized the amount of code to make it even easier to understand

Comment: That will do it, if you need a `TabView` inside a `NavigationView` you have to create your own. It is a common issue.